Path calculation in Neo4J with APOC. How to limit the path length using relationship distance value
I am trying to generate a random walk in using Neo4J and APOC Lib.
My goal is to calculate a random walk with a certain distance length.
The relationships are provided with a "distance" attribute in my database model. How can I include this parameter in the calculation? So that I get a path that is not limited by steps but by distance?
(Nodes = location, relation = connection)
This is my current query.
MATCH (m:location {osmid:33633426})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(m, {
    relationshipFilter: "connection",
    minLevel: 1,
    maxLevel: 50,
    uniqueness: "RELATIONSHIP_GLOBAL"
})
YIELD path
WITH path, length(path) AS hops
WHERE hops >= 10 
RETURN path, hops
ORDER BY hops
Limit 1;


How do you make the paths random? Is your plan to find all paths that satisfy the distance criteria and then pick them at random?

You can add a filter based on the sum of the distances found in the relationship type (:connection)
MATCH (m:location {osmid:33633426})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(m, {
    relationshipFilter: "connection",
    minLevel: 1,
    maxLevel: 50,
    uniqueness: "RELATIONSHIP_GLOBAL"
})
YIELD path
WITH path, 
// starting with totdistance, get the sum of distance found in each relationship type found in the traversal (path)
     REDUCE (totdistance=0, r in relationships(path) | 
            totdistance + r.distance ) AS totaldistance 
// you can then define what minimum distance you want (e.g. 10)
     WHERE totaldistance >= 10
RETURN path, totaldistance 
ORDER BY totaldistance 
LIMIT 1;

